# Piping Output from Split command to another function

Tags: python, bash, split, pipe

I am currently working on a script/command line that would allow me to do following:

1. archive and compress desired folder (tar)
2. split output of previous command/function into chunks of 100MB (split)
3. encrypt every single data chunk (gpg)

I've managed to write a python script that interacts with Linux terminal/bash and executes desired commands one by one, however I am working on rather substantial folder sizes (100GB +), which means that doing all of that sequentially takes at least 100GB for archive, 100GB for splits and 100GB for encryption.

I thought about using RAM disk to perform required operations in memory, but with folder sizes this seems like a dead end and if I script that in Python - I am unsure how I would get correct chunks in order on archive.

I've managed to combine archive and split functions using pipe in Linux, which both saves time and data required to be written to, however I am stuck on how I would go about piping output from split command (hundreds/thousands of files) to gpg command in a way that they are encrypted individually.

current process is as follows:
`tar {command with options} | split {command with options}` -> results in a split archive chunks.
python script that encrypts every file from previous split command tar.gz_0001 to tar.gz_0001.gpg etc.

Ideally I'd be able to do something akin to this:

```
tar {command with options} | split {command with options} | gpg {command with options}
```

which would produce files in format of:

```
filename.tar.gz_0001.gpg
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Key points are to save time and to not write data to the hard drive for intermediate steps.

Alternatively,
if someone can point out how I could accomplish Archiving and Splitting for large folders in python without writing so that that data can the be encrypted, that would also work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to create the `tar.gz`, save that file to disk, and then encrypt each 100MB chunk? Then you would avoid keeping the 100GB in RAM.

Comment: That is what I currently have and unless I find a more elegant solution, it will be the way that i'll proceed. I'll be dealing with Terabytes of data so that means I'll have to archive/split additional data and then encrypt that same data - effectively doubling the data written (including source it means 3 x data amount). I already reduced it from triplicate by piping tar and split together (4x data amount).